# Do not allow cancel to clear the Input File

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

In FileUpload Control if you select a file, it will show it's name and you can take control on it. Now think you click again on FileUpload to choose another file, and after opening File Dialog you decide to cancel and not to choose another file. Unfortunately FileUpload will clear its previous file in this situation.

I need to keep FileUpload Previous selected file if user decide to cancel selecting a new file.

Is this Possible?